# SafariDriver: inputElement.clear() doesn't work as expected

Tags: selenium, testing, safaridriver

This only happens on Safari with SafariDriver:

For a textinput element, clear() can clear the field indeed, but the following values sent using sendKeys() are actually extended with the original value.

Example:

1. Start -- input value: 1
2. input.clear() -- input value: empty
3. input.sendKeys(2) -- input value: 12

Also tried
`sendKeys(Key.HOME,Key.chord(Key.SHIFT,Key.END),newVal)` to select all and replace, but this simply not working. Nothing was selected.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `click` element first and then use `clear()` method to clear text, it works for me many times may be for you also:

```
WebElement myInputElement= driver.findElement("Locator value");
myInputElement.click();
myInputElement.clear();
myInputElement.sendKeys('Testing');
```